# Tasker to run scripts in terminal shell

Tags: tasker, shell, terminal, scripts

I have searched for this but till now I have not found any tasker that would be able to do this, so I decided to ask here.

Till now I have been using Trigger Pro as my favorite tasker but it lacks in advance usage, like run certain scripts over shell when triggered. I have been just able to run one script over Terminal app, by running a command when it launches that app, but through this I am just able to launch one script =/.

So any of you knows way to do this?

Comment: Can you tell us, why do you want to run your script *visibly*? That is it say, why not deploy a method that would silently run the script? [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) can do this well, so as Automate from LlamaLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by using Tasker.

Instructions:

- Create a named task.
- A1: Code >> Run Shell [Command: (insert any code you wish to run)  Store Output: (insert any variable which will retain the value of ouput - `stdout`) Store errors in : (insert a variable which stores errors - `stderr`)]
- Tap back to exit
- Link your task to your profile.

Note: for shell commands that require root you have to the tick the 'use root' option